# Encoded slash (%2F) in query parameter causes redirection to fail in Angular Application

Tags: angularjs, tomcat7, redirect, urlencode

In my angular application, I need to make GET call to a Tomcat server. This GET call requires query parameters which could contain special characters too like "+", "/", "/+"
GET call is being made from angular controller using $window.open with target as "_blank"

Currently the redirection is getting failed without any encoding.

So, I added encoding in .js file before the GET call is being made by using encodeURIComponent.

Then I added decoding logic using URLDecode.decode in backend java code to decode query parameters.

But still it doesn't work.

It works only if I encode query parameters twice within the .js file using encodeURIComponent twice.

I am trying to find the root cause for double encoding but no luck yet. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could share any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work by adding a `*` in path parameter in app.js. Adding a star means that the request will include multiple path parameters separated by `/`, and so angular will not try to encode `/` in the request.
Double encoding could also work but then the server side logic has to be modified to decode the request parameters twice and replace `%2B2F` by `%2F`